# Any treatment for Phragmidiaceae on blackberry bushes?

Tags: fungus

[image: Blackberry leaves with red discolouration]

I've noticed this on a few of the plants but doesn't seem to be affecting all of them. Is there any treatment for this? I've only read about prevention outside the growing season.

Comment: [This reference](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/its_that_time_of_year_for_orange_rust_in_brambles) seems to have all the answers. I don't have time to write up a full answer at the moment, so anyone who has time can feel free to do so.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It's very helpful!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you found the info you needed, self-answering is always encouraged. That way others with the same issue can benefit from what you learned as well.